# Combine sub-dataframes on joined keys using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Say I have the two following pandas dataframes:

```
DF1
id    n_id    col1    col2   col3    ...
1     1       ...     ...    ...
2     1       ...     ...    ...
3     2       ...     ...    ...
4     2       ...     ...    ...
5     4       ...     ...    ...
6     4       ...     ...    ...


DF2
id    n_id    col1    col2   col3    ...
1     1       ...     ...    ...
2     1       ...     ...    ...
3     3       ...     ...    ...
4     3       ...     ...    ...
5     4       ...     ...    ...
6     4       ...     ...    ...
```

Now what I want to do is **inner** join this two dataframes on `n_id` and connect each `n_id` with all the values produced from the result of a custom function `combine(DF1_n_id, DF2_n_id)`, so my result looks like:

```
DF_mix
id            n_id    col1    col2   col3    ...
1              1        \       |      /
...           ...       -    df1_mix   -   
s1_mix         1        /       |      \
s1_mix+1       4        \       |      /
...           ...       -    df4_mix   -
s4_mix+s1_mix  4        /       |      \
```

where:

```
dfi_mix = combine(DF1[n_id == i], DF2[n_id == i])
si_mix = n_rows(df1_mix)
```

I am not able to find the most efficient solution.
My mind first wandered around merge, but this produced something like a cartesian product on common values. Then I tried to join group by elements on `n_id` but this is not possible.
Thanks in advance!

Notes:
1. The index should be ignored.
2. `DF1[n_id == i]` can consist only of columns (i.e. `col1, col2, col3, ...`)
3. All the dataframes have the same columns (i.e. `id, n_id, col1, col2, col3, ...`)
4. `id` stands for the default index assigned by pandas

**Silly example:**

```
DF1
id    n_id    a    b   
1     1       1    1 
2     1       1    1 
3     2       1    2
4     2       1    2
5     4       1    4
6     4       1    4


DF2
id    n_id    a   b
1     1       2   1
2     1       2   1
3     3       2   3
4     3       2   3
5     4       2   4
6     4       2   4
```

`combine(df1, df2) = pd.concat`

```
DF_mix
id  n_id  a  b
1   1     1  1
2   1     1  1
3   1     2  1
4   1     2  1
5   4     1  4
6   4     1  4
7   4     2  4
8   4     2  4
```

Ofcourse `concat` could be replaced with anything as long as it returns a `DataFrame` of columns `a,b`.

Comment: Can you please post as what all you tried??

Comment: Could you produce some concrete example data and the intended output?

Comment: Also, if the "custom function" is necessary for the output, please post that as well.

Comment: If give my exact example the problem will become really specific. The custom function can be any function that takes the two sub-dataframes of A and of B for key `n_id` and returns one (with possibly a different number of rows). It is like the doing the [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) split apply combine strategy between the common `n_id` keys of the two datasets.